# R regex: remove times from character string

Tags: regex, r

I am attempting to remove/extract times from a character string.  The logic is that I am grabbing things that:

1. must begin with 0-2 digits
2. must be followed by a single colon
3. may be followed by either a colon or a period but do not have to
4. may be followed by 1-infinite digits (if previous condition is true)

Here's a MWE and what I've tried.  I'm almost there but I do not want `"6:33."` to be extracted but instead `"6:33"` as the advent of a colon or comma must be followed by 1 or more digits.  In this case the period is the end of the sentence not a part of the time.

```
text.var <-  c("R uses 1:5 for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.", 
    "At 3:00 we'll meet up and leave by 4:30:20.",
    "We'll meet at 6:33.", "He ran it in :22.34.")

pattern <- "\\(?[0-9]{0,2}\\)?\\:\\(?[0-9]{2}\\)?\\(?[:.]{0,1}\\)?\\(?[0-9]{0,}\\)?"

regmatches(text.var, gregexpr(pattern, text.var, perl = TRUE))

## [[1]]
## character(0)
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "3:00"    "4:30:20"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "6:33."
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] ":22.34"
```

**Desired Output**

```
## [[1]]
## character(0)
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "3:00"    "4:30:20"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "6:33"
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] ":22.34"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the following to fix your problem.

```
regmatches(text.var, gregexpr('\\d{0,2}:\\d{2}(?:[:.]\\d+)?', text.var, perl=T))
```

**Explanation**:

```
\d{0,2}   # digits (0-9) (between 0 and 2 times)
:         # ':'
\d{2}     # digits (0-9) (2 times)
(?:       # group, but do not capture (optional):
  [:.]    #   any character of: ':', '.'
  \d+     #   digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
)?        # end of grouping
```

**Note**: I removed the escaped parentheses because I am unclear why they are being used in the first place..

Comment: Hi @hwnd you also can shorten it to `\d{0,2}:\d{2}(?:[:.]\d+)?`

Comment: Both solutions work well, this was the first correct response.  A lot more readable than my own.  Thank you. +1

Comment: @TylerRinker Glad I could help out once again =)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
regmatches(text.var, gregexpr("(\\d{0,2}:\\d{2}(?:\\.\\d+)?)", text.var))
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/cS0nT7/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [42-46] `3:00`
MATCH 2
1.  [74-78] `4:30`
MATCH 3
1.  [78-81] `:20`
MATCH 4
1.  [104-108]   `6:33`
MATCH 5
1.  [126-132]   `:22.34`
```

Comment: @TylerRinker great, glad to help someone like you

Comment: I thought it inappropriately split the second target in the second element.

Comment: @BondedDust I think I messed things up in an edit where I tried to give double underscores.  I reverted to what Fede had (with `\\` vs. `\`) and added the R code to extract.